# Can't Create OpenStack Queue

Tags: java, queue, openstack, jclouds

I'm trying to create an OpenStack queue using Java and jclouds, but i couldn't, i followed the example [example](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/blob/934cdb085d7b1511af6a390484b414f995510901/rackspace/src/main/java/org/jclouds/examples/rackspace/cloudqueues/StreamMessages.java#L95), my code is:

```
MarconiApi marconiApi = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("openstack-marconi")
                .endpoint(Auth_URL)
                .credentials(tenantName + ":" + username, apiKey)
                .buildApi(MarconiApi.class);
                
String region = marconiApi.getConfiguredRegions().iterator().next();
QueueApi queueApi = marconiApi.getQueueApi(region, Publisher_ID);
queueApi.create("test");
```

and i get the error : `org.jclouds.rest.ResourceNotFoundException: org.jclouds.http.HttpResponseException: command: PUT http://controller:8888/queues/test HTTP/1.1 failed with response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found; content: []`

keep in mind I'm using

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jclouds-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.labs</groupId>
            <artifactId>openstack-marconi</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

so what I'm doing wrong? and are these functions for OpenStack Zaqar?, how to create a OpenStack queues?

Thanks